# Expanding a UIView without resizing or redrawing

Tags: ios, uiview, cgpath

Is it possible to have a UIView that can have its frame set repeatedly, e.g. increasing its size on the positive x axis, but without resizing or squeezing the image?

I would like to e.g. have a CGPath drawn into a 320 x 100 frame, but only show the frame increasing on the x value, with the 100 y value, so it reveals the image as it expands. edit: I already have the CGPath drawn, but it currently gets resized as the frame that holds it expands.

So the view should never redraw or resize its contents, but rather have its content fixed in position, but when its frame enlarged, only more of the image becomes visible.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you've drawn the view in its `drawRect:` method, the view's `contentMode` property determines what happens to the view's contents when its frame changes.

The values for `contentMode` are described under [`UIViewContentMode` in the *`UIView` Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW69).

By default, a view's `contentMode` is `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`:

> Scales the content to fit the size of itself by changing the aspect ratio of the content if necessary.

It sounds like you might want `UIViewContentModeTopLeft`:

> Aligns the content in the top-left corner of the view.

Comment: Thanks. I do draw the viewcontroller's view using drawRect, and then I have another UIView placed inside this viewController's view in IB, and that UIView calls its own drawRect function. Both views draw correctly, they are duplictes of one another, So I want to create a progress effect but slowly revealing the duplicate which is on top of the original. The issue is that none of the contentMode settings allow this.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Your answer combined with David's comment solved it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you have a primary view, and a UIImageView as a subview. If you set the autoResizingMask for the UIImageView to not resize - its just anchored to the left x and y axis - that should do it.

Comment: Thanks. It says in the docs however "The default value of this property is UIViewAutoresizingNone, which indicates that the view should not be resized at all."

Comment: So, you never said absolutely that the CGPath is a UIImage. I just created a project, added a UIImageView to it, added a button that changed the container view's width, and the image did not resize. So, if you have a containerView that has its clipsToBounds=YES, and a subview of a UIImage of what you want to disclose, and you slowly keep increasing the containerView's width, it will slowly disclose.

Comment: Im sorry, but this just does not work for me. I have a view that I override drawRect, which holds another view that has its drawRect overridden to apply the duplicate path of the original into a UIImage. I then use this UIImage to set the image of a UIImageView (which is a subview of the second view) so mainView>secondView>ImageView.image.I have tried clipsToBounds on these views, nothing changes. I get the original view displaying the path, then the duplicate applied UIImage is visible, but fits inside the view as it expands, do the path is all squashed and slowly stretches to its actual size

Comment: Ok, it works!! :) I had to combine your answer with Rob's. The UIImageView also needed to have its mode set to "Top Left" in IB.